# copying artifact to remote machine using jenkins-pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have running jenkins in windows machine, i have create build there and artifact is ready, But how can i transfer that artifact to remote machine. I have ssh key and user-id only.(need to be trafered over ssh)

Comment: Just a note, the default behavior of `archiveArtifacts` copies the artifacts from the slave to the master node. If you need to specify a different server (other than Jenkins master), then maybe look at the plugin suggested by @whitediver .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SCP plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SCP+plugin) to upload files.
Also, you may need to setup ssh client on your windows host.